# Two ODE planar systems that are orthogonal to each other

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given two planar systems X'=F(X) and X'=G(X) (so F and G are both $C^1$). Assume the dot product of F(X) and G(X) is always zero on $R^2$. Now if F has a closed orbit,  prove that G has a zero.

My attempt:

The first thing pops up in my mind is a circle (the closed orbit of F). On this circle, G(X) is perpendicular to F(X), and then there must be an equilibrium point inside the circle. However I cannot generalize my idea.

P.S.: this should be an easy exercise after learning the Poincare-Bendixson theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ has an equilibrium on the closed orbit of $x'=F(x)$, then you are done. Otherwise, along the closed orbit of $x'=F(x)$ the vector field $G$ points always inside or always outside, in view of the orthogonality of the two vector fields. So, by the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, there is a zero of $G$ inside the closed orbit.

Comment: would you please elaborate on how to apply the theorem?

Comment: Please let me know what you don't understand: the application is immediate.

Comment: In fact, I know if there's a limit cycle for G inside the closed orbit of F, then we have a zero for G. What if there is no such limit cycle?

Comment: I see, don't think like that: either 1) you have a zero of $G$ inside the closed orbit, and there is nothing to prove, or 2) there is no zero of $G$ inside. In the last case, Poincaré-Bendixson gives a closed orbit of $G$ inside the closed orbit of $F$. But from what you there would be a zero of $G$ inside. Contradiction! So, only possibility 1) holds.

Comment: oh yes it's really clear to me now! Thanks!